# Animation events isn't commited by TortoiseSVN in Unity3D

Tags: animation, events, svn, unity-game-engine, tortoisesvn

As topic title says, I added event to one of my animation in Unity3D and assigned function to it but when I want to commit it by TortoiseSVN, it doesn't appear to commit.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 3):

You should save project first (File -> Save Project). Once the files will be saved and written to disk, Subversion will put Modified status on the changed items and you could commit them to the repository.

Comment: Actually, It was my fault. I added event to read-only animation, so it can't be saved and it can't be committed.